# python: extract rows that a column value is more than 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

there is a dataframe as following:

```
id  year number
1   2016  3
1   2017  5
2   2016  1
2   2017  5
...
```

I want to extract the rows that groupby id and the value of number column is more than 3 in both 2016 and 2017.

for example in the above first 4 rows, the result is:

```
   id  year number
    1   2016  3
    1   2017  5
```

Thanks!

Comment: why last row is not included in your output?

Comment: because the id 2 , 2016 year, the number is less than 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare by `>=3` and use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[(df["number"] >= 3).groupby(df["id"]).transform('all')]
#alternative for reassign mask to column
#df = df[df.assign(number= df["number"] >= 3).groupby("id")['number'].transform('all')]
print (df1)
   id  year  number
0   1  2016       3
1   1  2017       5
```

Or use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration), but it should be slow if large DataFrame or many groups:

```
df1 = df.groupby("id").filter(lambda x: (x["number"] >= 3).all())
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> great_in_both_years = df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: (x["number"] >= 3).all())
>>> great_in_both_years
id
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

>>> df.loc[lambda x: x["id"].map(great_in_both_years)]
   id  year  number
0   1  2016       3
1   1  2017       5
```